# Choosing projection for running polygon intersections at global scale (i.e, geodesic intersections)?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, intersection, sf, geodesic

**How do I choose a projection for intersecting two global polygon datasets in WGS-84 (4326), and get accurate estimates of their overlap area?**

I searched the internet for answers to this question, and all turned out to be wrong I think, except for the lovely projection table posted by [Jochen Albrecht](http://www.geo.hunter.cuny.edu/%7Ejochen/gtech201/lectures/lec6concepts/map%20coordinate%20systems/how%20to%20choose%20a%20projection.htm).

So, when you are intersecting two polygons in 4326, you will need currently in R (`sf` package, as of 12/2020) to reproject them into a common projection, run the intersection, and then back-transform them into 4326 to get a correct estimate of the overlap area (using sf::st_area).

Most sources (e.g. [Chapter 6 Reprojecting geographic data](https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/reproj-geo-data.html) of Geocomputation with R) will recommend an azimuthal equidistant or equal-area projection centered on the focal polygon, which if you have lots of polygons (I have >200K), means a for-loop.  Not that slow actually, but many of the suggested projections will do geodesic intersections between polygons with some bias.

Comment: "Best" questions are problematic here, since they tend to be *opinion-based*. In fact, your *answer the question in the Question* approach is actually called out in the [Don't Ask](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) help page as a style of question to avoid.

Comment: This is not an opinion "best", this is a lowest- to zero-bias best.  The best solution has zero bias, so it's not up for debate. I never said I answered it, I said I THINK I answered it, and I am looking for confirmation or rebuttal.  So it is a question, legitimately. This question is not answered elsewhere on this site, I am pretty sure.

Comment: Confirmation/rebuttal is a discussion request, but GIS SE uses a Focused question/Best answer model. This would be appropriate for [Chat], if Chat had enough volume to support this kind of discussion.

Comment: I am sorry, i don't mean to be a pain, but this is a focused question, with one best answer.  I even supplied an example dataset to allow someone to support or rebut the potential solution.  please leave this post up.  happy to rephrase as needed.

Comment: I think you should restructure your question into a separate question and answer in the areas reserved for each. I think you should title it as “Choosing projection for ...”.

Comment: done.  hopefully this passes muster now.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use a projection (except for making maps; or when you must use an algorithm that really cannot deal with angular data). For area computations in R, you should use the lon/lat data. That is the best way to avoid inaccuracies. The thing to consider is the vertex density of the polygons. If that is too low, the intersection does not happen at the right (close enough) place. But you can increase the vertex density (see my example below). If low vertex density is a problem, making lon/lat intersections inaccurate, projecting the data to a planar crs does not help at all. That is a common, but big, misconception.

Here is an extreme example. I do not know `sf` very well, so I use sp/raster/geosphere

Example data

```
library(raster)
crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
# very large polygons with very few vertices    
p1 <- spPolygons(rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20)), crs=crs)
p2 <- spPolygons(rbind(c(-125,0), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45), c(-125,0)), crs=crs)
```

First the naïve approach

```
x1 <- intersect(p1, p2) 
raster::area(x1) / 1e+12 
#[1] 50.02117

plot(bind(p1, p2), border=c("red", "blue"), lwd=5)
plot(x1, add=TRUE, density=20)
```

Now add vertices (in this case I ask for at least one every 1000 m)

```
pp1 <- geosphere::makePoly(p1, interval=1000, sp=TRUE)
pp2 <- geosphere::makePoly(p2, interval=1000, sp=TRUE)
```

The number of vertices was

```
nrow(geom(p1)) - 1
#[1] 4
```

And is now

```
nrow(geom(pp1))-1
[1] 40785
```

Try again. The area of intersection is 2.5 times larger.

```
x2 <- intersect(pp1, pp2) 
raster::area(x2) / 1e+12 
#[1] 127.8921
 
plot(bind(pp1, pp2), border=c("red", "blue"), lwd=5)
plot(x2, add=TRUE, density=20)
```

I am implementing these things in `terra` to streamline and speed things up.

A comparison using a projection:

```
crs2 <- "+proj=sinu"
p1q <- spTransform(p1, crs2)
p2q <- spTransform(p2, crs2)
qi <- intersect(p1q, p2q)
```

Areas are way off

```
area(p1) / 1e+12
#[1] 211.2407
area(p1q) / 1e+12
#[1] 127.7939
area(p2) / 1e+12
#[1] 161.2815
area(p2q )/ 1e+12
#[1] 107.1201
```

And the intersected area is about as bad as the naive approach

```
area(x1) / 1e+12
#[1] 50.02117
area(x2) / 1e+12
#[1] 127.8921
area(qi) / 1e+12
#[1] 56.00833

plot(bind(p1q, p2q), border=c("red", "blue"), lwd=5)
plot(qi, add=TRUE, density=20)
```

From the comment (`sinu` is not a great example):

```
 crs3 <- "+proj=eqc"; 
 p1q <- spTransform(p1, crs3); 
 p2q <- spTransform(p2, crs3); 
 qi <- intersect(p1q, p2q); 
 qi2 <-spTransform(qi, crs); 
 area(x1) / 1e+12; 
 #[1] 50.02117
 area(qi2) / 1e+12
 #[1] 50.02117
```

Notes (in repsonse to the comments):

`raster::intersect` is a wrapper for `rgeos::gIntersection` that also keeps the attributes (but the latter should be faster if you do not care about that). You can also use `sf::st_intersection`. Since you are not projecting, the data-line should not be an issue?.

You can find out if it matters by changing interval in makePoly. You can check the number of vertices with `nrow(geom(p1)` (see above). My experience with the WDPA is that it has poor topology (e.g. self intersections), but much detail, so none of this might be of much practical concern.

Whether adding vertices adds unintended realism would depend on how the data were created. If they were GPS points it would avoid losing accuracy and I it would be good practice (best practice would be an algorithm that finds the correct intersection without such help, e.g. s2)). But the boundaries are more likely from tracing on a map. Then it would depend on the underlying map projection that was used for that. So it may be impossible to really know?

Comment: Hi Robert, before I comment here, please first let me just thank you A) for responding in such a helpful and informative way, and B) for tirelessly innovating and maintaining the packages that I use for research every day.  Corresponding with you definitely ticks a bucket list for me.

Comment: I had no idea that raster::intersect worked in 4326, and obviously I would have used it had I known.  Does it handle the date line well as well?

Comment: one point I wanted to raise is that if you use a sinusoidal projection in your example, the error is baked in from the projection distortion. if you instead use an equirectangular projection, and remember to backconvert to 4326 for area calculation after the intersect, it is equivalent to x1.  I can't figure out how to newline in the comments, but here's the R code in one line: crs3 <- "+proj=eqc"; p1q <- spTransform(p1, crs3); p2q <- spTransform(p2, crs3); qi <- intersect(p1q, p2q); qi2 <-spTransform(qi, crs); qi2 <-spTransform(qi, crs); 
area(x1) / 1e+12; area(qi2) / 1e+12

Comment: All that said, the vertex density issue is one I hadn't even considered, and it is a little mind-bending for me in a data model kind of way.  It makes sense, but I am trying to decide if I should second-guess the folks who created the WDPA dataset by adding vertices.  Is that adding unintended realism to a dataset that is already natively in 4326, with lots of vertices?  Or is that standard best practices when working with large polygons at a global scale?  And at what scale does it begin to really matter: do polygons have to be larger than a certain size or length?  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. I moved my comments to the answer, as this appendix was getting very long

Comment: well at the risk of adding too much here, thanks again.  the topology in the WDPA is a nightmare indeed; let's just say that it took me a week solid to make it valid, delete overlaps (keeping the higher protected status), and then buffer it in various ways.  It refuses s2 validity altogether in its current state, and none of the standard tricks work.  As it stands, it sounds like I am safe keeping things as I did them, with the caveat that now I know how to go back and test my assumptions using geosphere when I have this manuscript finished.  MUCH appreciated sir.

Answer (score 1):

Jochen's table led me to an accurate answer (I think/hope).

Here is the answer I came up with.  First, if you can run this in ArcGIS Pro, go for it, because it has a geodesic option, but it is not a possibility for my analysis (too much data, etc.).  Second, try the new [s2 functionality](https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2020/06/17/s2.html) in `sf` in R. Sadly, I could not use the new s2 functionality since my data kept throwing validity errors. But it turns out there may be a simple solution.

If you have a global dataset that stretches over the international dateline, the first step is to clip it in two at the dateline.  That solves a lot of problems and makes the solution below possible. if you can't do that, and the solutions above don't work, try the local azimuth solution (see below).

So I did some trial analyses, and I think what you actually want is a projection that preserves SHAPE, not distance or area.  And the best projections for shape are cylindrical, which means that sf's basic equirectangular projection is best for geodesic intersection (i.e., the default st_intersection on 4326 data, which throws an error you can ignore).

Here's an example set of analyses that show that equirectangular works best, with zero bias in area estimation between two large example polygons.  An equidistant azimuthal projection, centered on the local polygon centroid, had the second lowest bias.

```
library(sf)

#  create a polygon box (pol) centered on 0,0 lat/long, a second shifted half a degree east (pol2, and a third (pol1b) representing the area of overlap. 

center_loc = 0
a=center_loc-0.5
b=center_loc+0.5
pol = st_polygon(list(rbind(c(a,a), c(b,a), c(b,b), c(a,b), c(a,a))))
pol2 = st_polygon(list(rbind(c(0,a), c(1,a), c(1,b), c(0,b), c(0,a))))
pol1b=st_polygon(list(rbind(c(0,a), c(b,a), c(b,b), c(0,b), c(0,a))))

plot(pol); plot(pol2, add=TRUE); plot(pol1b, add=TRUE, col="red") 

pol=st_sfc(pol)
st_crs(pol)=4326
pol2=st_sfc(pol2)
st_crs(pol2)=4326
pol1b=st_sfc(pol1b)
st_crs(pol1b)=4326

#  okay!  now you can calculate the area of each:
st_area(pol)
st_area(pol2)
st_area(pol1b); truval=st_area(pol1b)


#  now to transform the focal poly,  pol, to a few different azimuthal systems.
pol_aeqd=st_transform(pol, "+proj=aeqd +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") #aeqd
pol_l=st_transform(pol, "+proj=laea") #lambert
pol_st=st_transform(pol, "+proj=stere") #stereographic

#  now to do the same for pol2 (note that the projection is centered on the neighboring polygon, which we would do for a local azimuthal projection) 
pol2_aeqd=st_transform(pol2, "+proj=aeqd +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") #aeqd
pol2_l=st_transform(pol2, "+proj=laea") #lambert
pol2_st=st_transform(pol2, "+proj=stere") #stereographic

#  and to intersect and back convert to 4326.
inter_a=st_intersection(pol_aeqd, pol2_aeqd)
inter_l=st_intersection(pol_l, pol2_l)
inter_st=st_intersection(pol_st, pol2_st)
fin_a=st_transform(inter_a, st_crs(4326))
fin_l=st_transform(inter_l, st_crs(4326))
fin_st=st_transform(inter_st, st_crs(4326))

#  I added equirectangular here for fun...
inter_fun=st_intersection(pol, pol2)


#  now for the results, showing the bias of different projections.
st_area(fin_a); truval-st_area(fin_a)
st_area(fin_l); truval-st_area(fin_l)
st_area(fin_st); truval-st_area(fin_st)
st_area(inter_fun); truval-st_area(inter_fun)

#  So it appears that equirectangular does the best job maintaining shape, so it is the most accurate for intersection, as long as you back-transform to 4326 for overlap area calc following intersection.  

##  and it hold true if you go to a random location, like y+20, x+100
coords=rbind(c(a,a), c(b,a), c(b,b), c(a,b), c(a,a))
coord_rhalf=rbind(c(0,a), c(b,a), c(b,b), c(0,b), c(0,a))
plot(coords[,1]+10, coords[,2])
pol3=st_polygon(list(cbind(coords[,1]+100, coords[,2]+20)))
pol3b=st_polygon(list(cbind(coords[,1]+100.5, coords[,2]+20)))
pol3c=st_polygon(list(cbind(coord_rhalf[,1]+100, coord_rhalf[,2]+20)))
pol3=st_sfc(pol3); st_crs(pol3)=4326
pol3b=st_sfc(pol3b); st_crs(pol3b)=4326
pol3c=st_sfc(pol3c); st_crs(pol3c)=4326

st_area(pol3); st_area(pol3b); st_area(pol3c); truval2=st_area(pol3c)
#
st_area(st_intersection(pol3, pol3b)); truval2-st_area(st_intersection(pol3, pol3b))
pol3_a=st_transform(pol3, "+proj=aeqd +lat_0=20 +lon_0=100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") #aeqd
pol3b_a=st_transform(pol3b, "+proj=aeqd +lat_0=20 +lon_0=100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") #aeqd
st_intersection(pol3_a, pol3b_a) %>% st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>% st_area()
truval2-st_intersection(pol3_a, pol3b_a) %>% st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>% st_area()
#
```